# geckodriver path error - if i am using a batch file to start my python script

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I want to execute my python script by a batch file. I have no problem if i execute my python script manually, but if i use a batch file to execute it then i get the "'geckodriver' executable needs to be in Path" error. In both ways I use the same interpreter.

My batch file:

```
C:\Users\murac\PycharmProjects\IP_Klima_Strom\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\murac\PycharmProjects\IP_Klima_Strom\main.py
pause
```

my error warning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\murac\PycharmProjects\IP_Klima_Strom\main.py", line 166, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=browser_profile, options=opts)
  File "C:\Users\murac\PycharmProjects\IP_Klima_Strom\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\murac\PycharmProjects\IP_Klima_Strom\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

[My path Confi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4R9f.png)

I alreay updated my geckodriver and updated the path too, but nothing has changed. DO you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: Also add your PATH configuration.

Comment: Hi there, i have added the path confi in my question above. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess if you put you geckodriver in the same folder with script its gonna work

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem! :)